# Ordenar diccionario sin sort

Tags: python, diccionarios, ordenamiento, pycharm

Tengo este diccionario, Para obtener una lista con la población ordenada en forma descendente, implemente y use la siguiente función: • ordenar población recibe como parámetro el diccionario inei, y utilizando el método Insert Sort retorna la lista de la población ordenada en forma descendente

```
inei = {"Molina": 175237, "Callao": 426649, "Victoria": 174958,
        "Comas": 532403, "Agustino": 194474, "Carabayllo": 305963,
        "Olivos": 377532, "Cieneguilla": 47860, "Lince": 51054,
        "Independencia": 220654, "Jesus Maria": 73439, "Ate": 638345,
        "Carmen Legua": 43156, "Mi Peru": 52722, "Ventanilla ": 356040,
        "Lima": 276861, "Ancon": 43951, "Barranco": 30698, "Bellavista": 78489,
        "La Perla": 64111, "Brena": 77291, "Chaclacayo": 44271, "Chorrillos": 330483}
```

Debe salir así, no se puede usar la función sort:

```
Poblacion ordenada: [638345, 532403, 426649, 377532, 356040, 330483, 305963, 276861, 220654, 194474, 175237, 174958, 78489, 77291, 73439, 64111, 52722, 51054, 47860, 44271, 43951, 43156, 30698]
```

Comment: No se entiende qué interés tendría esta pregunta en no usar `sort`, siendo el método más recomendado para hacer ordenaciones. Con el fin de que sea útil al resto de personas que usan este foro, por favor, explica _mínimamente_ el motivo por el que no puedes usar `sort`.

Comment: Hola, ya lo resolví. Pero igual estoy en la parte de funciones y me piden que no me vaya por el camino fácil y rápido.

Comment: Hola. Me alegro que lo hayas resuelto. Si alguna de las respuestas que han proporcionado te ha sido válida, puedes marcarla. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes el diccionario con tus datos:

```
inei = {"Molina": 175237, "Callao": 426649, "Victoria": 174958,
        "Comas": 532403, "Agustino": 194474, "Carabayllo": 305963,
        "Olivos": 377532, "Cieneguilla": 47860, "Lince": 51054,
        "Independencia": 220654, "Jesus Maria": 73439, "Ate": 638345,
        "Carmen Legua": 43156, "Mi Peru": 52722, "Ventanilla ": 356040,
        "Lima": 276861, "Ancon": 43951, "Barranco": 30698, "Bellavista": 78489,
        "La Perla": 64111, "Brena": 77291, "Chaclacayo": 44271, "Chorrillos": 330483}
```

Declaramos una lista final donde insertarás los values de tu diccionario ordenados:

```
lista_final = []
```

Cogemos los values de tu diccionario, que retorna un objeto dict_values y lo convertimos en lista:

```
lista_inei = list(inei.values())
```

Luego, en un while loop mantenemos la iteracción mientras:

- Cogemos el primer elemento.
- Recorremos cada número de la lista que creamos.
- Si el número es mayor que el elemento que hemos guardado como mayor, el elemento máximo será uno nuevo.
- Agregamos este nuevo elemento a la lista final.
- Eliminamos este elemento de la lista que creamos temporal para que el while no sea infinito

```
while lista_inei:
    elemento_maximo = lista_inei[0]
    for numero in lista_inei:
        if numero > elemento_maximo:
            elemento_maximo = numero
    lista_final.append(elemento_maximo)
    lista_inei.remove(elemento_maximo)
```

Resultado:

```
print(lista_final)

$ -> python3 order.py 
[638345, 532403, 426649, 377532, 356040, 330483, 305963, 276861, 220654, 194474, 175237, 174958, 78489, 77291, 73439, 64111, 52722, 51054, 47860, 44271, 43951, 43156, 30698]
```

Aunque es mucho más fácil con sort, tendrás razones para hacerlo sin él.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo algo muy simple y super facil de entender y sobre todo **SIN** usar la funcion `sort`:
Tienes tu diccionario:

```
inei = {"Molina": 175237, "Callao": 426649, "Victoria": 174958,
        "Comas": 532403, "Agustino": 194474, "Carabayllo": 305963,
        "Olivos": 377532, "Cieneguilla": 47860, "Lince": 51054,
        "Independencia": 220654, "Jesus Maria": 73439, "Ate": 638345,
        "Carmen Legua": 43156, "Mi Peru": 52722, "Ventanilla ": 356040,
        "Lima": 276861, "Ancon": 43951, "Barranco": 30698, "Bellavista": 78489,
        "La Perla": 64111, "Brena": 77291, "Chaclacayo": 44271, "Chorrillos": 330483}
```

Lo que vamos a hacer primero que nada es crear una lista vacía donde agregaremos los elementos ya ordenados, yo la llamare `lf`:

```
lf = []
```

Despues vamos a obtener los valores de las claves de los diccionarios y los almacenamos e una lista:

```
l = list(inei.values())
```

Ahora simplemente obtendremos el elemento mayor con la función `max()`, obtenemos su indice, lo agregamos a la lista final, y posteriormente lo eliminamos de la lista de valores `l`. Repetimos el proceso el numero de elementos.

```
for element in range(len(l)):
    maximo = max(l)
    maxIndex = l.index(maximo)
    lf.append(l[maxIndex])
    l.pop(maxIndex)
```

Finalmente imprimimos el resultado con `print(lf)` y obtenemos:

```
[638345, 532403, 426649, 377532, 356040, 330483, 305963, 276861, 220654, 194474, 175237, 174958, 78489, 77291, 73439, 64111, 52722, 51054, 47860, 44271, 43951, 43156, 30698]
```

### Codigo Completo

```
inei = {"Molina": 175237, "Callao": 426649, "Victoria": 174958,
        "Comas": 532403, "Agustino": 194474, "Carabayllo": 305963,
        "Olivos": 377532, "Cieneguilla": 47860, "Lince": 51054,
        "Independencia": 220654, "Jesus Maria": 73439, "Ate": 638345,
        "Carmen Legua": 43156, "Mi Peru": 52722, "Ventanilla ": 356040,
        "Lima": 276861, "Ancon": 43951, "Barranco": 30698, "Bellavista": 78489,
        "La Perla": 64111, "Brena": 77291, "Chaclacayo": 44271, "Chorrillos": 330483}

lf = []
l = list(inei.values())
for element in range(len(l)):
    maximo = max(l)
    maxIndex = l.index(maximo)
    lf.append(l[maxIndex])
    l.pop(maxIndex)

print(lf)
```

Answer (score -1):

Disculpa no se si entendi bien, pero si tienes que retornar una lista donde te interesan solo los numeros ordenados en forma descendente

podrias obtener los valores del diccionario, convertirlos en una lista y ahi utilizar un algoritmo para ordenarlos

lista = list(inei.values())

ordenas la lista y devuelves esta

Comment: Publica tu còdigo. Sin un código que podamos verificar, esta es sòlo una opiniòn sin respaldo. Puede estar bien, puede estar mal. Vaya uno a saber; no has demostrado que funciona.